# Java Vigenere Cipher

Tags: java, encryption, vigenere

I'am trying to decipher Vigenere_Cipher 
when i enter `BEXR TKGKTRQFARI` the output is `JAVAPROGRAMMING` But i want 
to put space like `JAVA PROGRAMMING`.

My Code

```
public static String VigenereDecipher(String text) {
    String keyword = "SECRET";
    String decipheredText = "";
    text = text.toUpperCase();
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        char c = text.charAt(i);
        if (c < 'A' || c > 'Z') continue;
        decipheredText += (char)((c - keyword.charAt(j) + 26) % 26 + 'A');
        j = ++j % keyword.length();
    }  
    return decipheredText;
}
```

Comment: When I enter `BEXR TKGKTRQFARI` ,I get `TI ZIXDYOVIUYSVK` - when I enter `JAVA PROGRAMMING`, I get `BEXR TKGKTRQFARI` - so something is off with your example here.

Comment: sorry ,this was encrypt, i edit it.

Comment: This kind of ciphertext will reveal information about the plaintext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're explicitly ignoring the spaces. You simply need to add this line:

```
if (c == ' ') {
   decipheredText += ' ';
}
```

Make sure to put it right before this line:

```
if (c < 'A' || c > 'Z') continue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are ignoring the space. Check for space as you are checking for character range 'A' to 'Z' and add it to decipheredText as space only as you don't want space to treated as another character.